# Bootstrap Navbar is not completely responsive, original navbar is still showing

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, responsive

When I look at my navbar when on my phone, the toggle button etc. is showing and working, but I first have to click a button before the original (non-responsive) navbar dissapears. So the navbar that is on my full non-responsive website, is still showing when only the responsive navbar should be showing. The weird thing is, when I click on the toggle button, the non-responsive navbar dissapears and everything works fine then.

```
<header class="main_menu_sec navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <div class="lft_hd">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.PNG" alt=""/></a>
                </div>
            </div>          
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <div class="rgt_hd">                    
                    <div class="main_menu">
                        <nav id="nav_menu">
                            <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>   
                        <div id="navbar">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#abt_sec">About Us</a></li>                                                        
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#skill_sec">Skills</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#pr_sec">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#protfolio_sec">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ctn_sec">Contact Us</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#tm_sec">Team</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>      
                        </nav>          
                    </div>                  

                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</header>
```

Comment: take a look at this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: This is helping! Thanks!!

Comment: Oh, I was too early.. The navbar is just fully hidden

Comment: Say I wanna use " class="hidden-xs" ", where should I put it to let the non-responsive navbar dissapear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add collapse navbar-collapse to the place to collapse on phone.

Working snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<header class="main_menu_sec navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <div class="lft_hd">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.PNG" alt="LOGO HERE"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>          
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <div class="rgt_hd">                    
                    <div class="main_menu">
                        <nav id="nav_menu">
                            <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>   
                        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#abt_sec">About Us</a></li>                                                        
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#skill_sec">Skills</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#pr_sec">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#protfolio_sec">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ctn_sec">Contact Us</a></li>
                                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#tm_sec">Team</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>      
                        </nav>          
                    </div>                  

                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</header>
<div>
```

Comment: It is working for the responsive website, but the text dissapears in the normal non-responsive navbar

Comment: @Roos It should not happen as it worked on my website

Comment: @Roos I've inserted a snippet to my post, and I can't see any text dissapers

Comment: It's actually working now (thank you!!), but the responsive navbar has a very small width, which means that you can only see a couple of letters per line

Comment: It looks like the navbar is stuck between the icon in the navbar and the toggle button.. - The responsive navbar should be under the icon and the toggle button

Answer (score 0):

You need collapse class with navbar id

```
<header class="main_menu_sec navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <div class="lft_hd">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.PNG" alt=""/></a>
            </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
            <div class="rgt_hd">                    
                <div class="main_menu">
                    <nav id="nav_menu">
                        <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>   
                    <div id="navbar" class="collapse">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#abt_sec">About Us</a></li>                                                        
                            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#skill_sec">Skills</a></li>
                            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#pr_sec">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#protfolio_sec">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ctn_sec">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#tm_sec">Team</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>      
                    </nav>          
                </div>                  

            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: It is working for the responsive website, but the text dissapears in the normal non-responsive navbar